# ES6 yield (yield 1)(yield 2)(yield 3)()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, yield

```
function* generatorFunction() {
  yield (yield 1)(yield 2)(yield 3)();
}
var iterator = generatorFunction();

// [1, 2, 3]
var iteratedOver = [iterator.next().value, iterator.next().value, iterator.next().value];
```

I'm not sure how this works.

`yield` doesn't return a function reference, so what are the parenthetical statements like `(yield 2)` doing - are they fat arrow anonymous functions without bodies?  How are they called using partial application like that?

I'm missing something here, can someone explain?

---

Update: Tried on three browsers, Chrome 50.0.2661.86, Safari  9.1 (50.0.2661.86), Firefox 44.0.2, all perform without errors.

[ESFiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/inngmpnk/) also executes it without errors.

Commenters report Babel executes without errors as well.

The source of the question is from http://tddbin.com/#?kata=es6/language/generator/send-function, the second kata.

Comment: Your code example doesn't run for me. `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function`

Comment: `yield` returns whatever you pass into `.next(…)`. You're just lucky that you've only called `.next()` 2 times, it would throw the next time.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, but then it begs the question... what led you to believe that this code was valid in the first place? Did you see it somewhere?

Comment: @Ben: That link produces errors in the output. Interesting about Safari though.

Comment: @Bergi 3 calls, actually, that correspond to the three "inner" `yields`.

Comment: @squint `Chrome  50.0.2661.86` was giving me trouble before with `Reflect`, which was working fine in `Safari 9.1 (50.0.2661.86)`.  The sample above works fine in both.

Comment: @Ben: Oh, right, it *does* throw on your third call. Your first one yields 1, the second yields 2, and only then the value you passed into the second call would be tried to be called (which fails in your case).

Comment: @Bergi yes, I think? :) it sounds like you might know what's going on - can you elaborate?

Comment: @Ben: Heh, congrats, looks like you've found a babel bug :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm not sure how this works.

Uh, yeah, it *shouldn't work*. It's only working because of a bug in Babel.

> `yield` doesn't return a function reference, so what are the parenthetical statements like `(yield 2)` doing - are they fat arrow anonymous functions without bodies? How are they called using partial application like that?

No, it's really just standard function application, no magic. `yield` *could* return a function reference, and when it does this might work. When it doesn't, it will throw an exception on the third `.next()` call.

As an example for a working version:

```
function* generatorFunction() {
  yield (yield 1)(yield 2)(yield 3)();
}
var test = (a) => {
  console.log(a);
  return (b) => {
    console.log(b);
    return (c) => {
      console.log(c);
      return 4;
    };
  };
};
var iterator = generatorFunction();
iterator.next(); // {value: 1, done: false}
iterator.next(test); // {value: 2, done: false}
iterator.next("a"); // "a" {value: 3, done: false}
iterator.next("b"); // "b" undefined {value: 4, done: false}
iterator.next("d"); // {value: undefined, done: true}
```

So how does this work? Those nested/chained `yield` statements should better be written as

```
function* generatorFunction() {
  let fn1 = yield 1;
  let a = yield 2;
  let fn2 = fn1(a);
  let b = yield 3;
  let fn3 = fn2(b);
  let res = fn3();
  let d = yield res;
  return undefined;
}
```

> Commenters report Babel executes without errors as well.

That's because of a babel bug. If you check the [transpiler output](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=function*%20generatorFunction()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20yield%20(yield%201)(yield%202)(yield%203)()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Avar%20iterator%20%3D%20generatorFunction()%3B%0D%0Avar%20iteratedOver%20%3D%20%5Biterator.next().value%2C%20iterator.next().value%2C%20iterator.next().value%5D%3B), it actually behaves like

```
function* generatorFunction() {
  let fn1 = yield 1;
  let a = yield 2;
  let b = yield 3;
  // these are no more executed with only 3 `next` calls
  let fn2 = fn1(a);
  let fn3 = fn2(b);
  let res = fn3();
  let d = yield res;
  return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Anyone wants to report this bug?

Comment: Filed on [`regenerator`](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator/issues/244) and in [`Babel`](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T7327). Thanks for tracking that down.